# Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

Tags: gnome, 14.04

In my ubuntu gnome was `3.9.90`, I added `Gnome 3.12` ppa via :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

Now I do `dist-upgrade` and lost ctrl+alt+t shortcut for terminal

Answer (score 1):

you can change the keyboard shortcuts in system settings. go to:

system settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts